# Are cardinal numbers sets in ZFC?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic, cardinals

Are cardinal numbers sets in ZFC, or just proper classes? If they are sets, what is their structure?

Comment: @S.Panja-1729 this is a common abbreviation for [Zermelo–Fraenkel set theory with the axiom of choice](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zermelo%E2%80%93Fraenkel_set_theory)

Comment: Do you mean one cardinal number or the collection of all?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. Since every set can be well ordered, we identify the cardinal numbers with specific ordinals. Namely a set is a cardinal number if and only if it is an ordinal (transitive set and we'll ordered by $\in$) and no smaller ordinal is equipotent with it.

Comment: So, in light of your answer, e.g. $\mathbb{N} = \omega = \aleph _0$ in ZFC?

Comment: That's one way of looking at it. But $\Bbb N$ is a non-set theoretic notion, which we can model using the set $\omega$ internally to the set theoretic universe; and $\aleph_0$ is a term for a cardinal, which is represented by the ordinal $\omega$, but it sets the context of cardinals rather than ordinals, because the two systems are very different (e.g. $\omega+\omega\neq\omega$ as ordinal addition, but $\aleph_0+\aleph_0=\aleph_0$ as cardinals).

Comment: I guess, then, that the equality is true in virtue of the internal nomenclature of ZFC, and not in some platonic sense - just as the natural number two is the set containing zero and one, which is true within ZFC but nonsense in the platonic sense of the phrase.

Comment: I don't know about "the platonic sense of the phrase". If there is a Platonic mathematical universe, and if it happened to be a set theoretic universe of $\sf ZFC$ then it is very much not nonsense. But if you think about mathematics as a type theoretic thing, then this is a type mismatch, to ask $1\in 2$ or $0\subseteq 3$. I prefer to see set theory as the CPU on which we run mathematics.

Comment: Well, for most platonists (notice the lowercase 'P') the set {0,1} and the natural number 2 are two entirely different entities...

Comment: I always felt weird believing in things. Including the existence, or lack thereof, of various abstract concepts as physical constructs. And what if there is a mathematical universe and it is in fact a set theoretic universe of $\sf ZFC$? Of course can *model* $\Bbb N$ using $\omega$, but we can also model it in other ways (e.g. construct $\Bbb R$ in whatever way you'd like, and identify $\Bbb N$ there, which is not $\omega$ anymore).

Answer (score 2):

Cardinalities ($>0$) are not sets if you define them as equivalence classes under bijectivity. But thanks to the C in ZFC, each of these classes contains at least one ordinal, and hence a smallest ordinal. So if you define cardinalities as ordinals that cannot be bijected to a proper subset, then cardinalities are sets.

Comment: Since the question said "cardinal _numbers_", I would assume we were talking about equivalence classes of ordinals anyway, and then you wouldn't need AC. But since the OP included choice there is no real difference.

Answer (score 0):

They are sets. Usual definition is that cardinal numbers are least ordinal numbers of a given cardinality. Therefore, each cardinal numbers is also a ordinal, so their structure depend on how you define ordinals.